# with rstudio and github, issue with renamed repo

Tags: r, git, github, rstudio

I had a repository named *tags*, I renamed it to *tag*.

I then created a new repository named *tags* (the old name of the first one).

Now when commiting from R Studio both projects try to commit to the same repository (*tags*).

I initiated my projects with :

```
shell("git remote add origin https://github.com/moodymudskipper/tag.git", intern = TRUE)
shell("git push -u origin master",intern = TRUE)
```

and

```
shell("git remote add origin https://github.com/moodymudskipper/tags.git",intern = TRUE)
shell("git push -u origin master",intern = TRUE)
```

And after this I only committed through *Rstudio*'s API and *usethis* functions, I don't know much more than that about *git*.

Links to the packages :

- https://github.com/moodymudskipper/tag
- https://github.com/moodymudskipper/tags

How can I sort this out ?

Comment: Try to intialize with `git init` `git commit` after checking the the status

Comment: Do the `.git/config` files both list `tags.git` in the remote section? This might be informative: https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-a-remotes-url

Comment: @r2evans they do, should I rename the relevant one to `tag.git` and try again ?

Comment: I've done manual-editing of those files before, but never when I have commits, branches, tags, etc. If you do `grep -rli tags.git .git/*`, you may find multiple files referencing the relevant URL ... and manually editing files beyond `.git/config` is not my forte. But if (at least) one of this repos is mostly empty (and/or that `grep -rli` revealed nothing else), you are likely "safe-ish" editing it by-hand.

Comment: @akrun `git init` + `git commit` returned a message saying it was up to date

Comment: I had similar kind of issue couple of days back, don't remember the exact code I used, but it was similar and got resolved

Comment: @IceCreamToucan I don't have any uncommited change and I want to push everything, so I guess I could backup the project, delete all the git stuff and start over with a forced push...

Comment: solved! I used notepad++ to look for tags.git and the only change was indeed only in `.git/config`, I just renamed manually and could push the changes smoothly. Thanks @r2evans! If you care to make an answer out of this I'll gladly accept it. Happy to self answer if not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm hesitant to throw this out as an answer, but: you can manually edit the `./.git/config` file to update the `[remote ...]` section to change the remote URL. I have done this confidently enough with an empty repo ...

Check for presence of the tag with `grep -rli tags.git .git/*`; if all you get is `.git/config`, then you're good to edit and move on. If you find other files, though, I don't know for certain that they will be updated as you continue with your git remote work. In that case, it might be helpful to look at https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-a-remotes-url in order to *formally* change the URL.